# Error while opening matlab 2019 from ubuntu 20.04 terminal

Tags: drivers, matlab

I am getting following error when I open matlab from terminal of ubuntu 20.04.

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

System uses inbuilt intel graphics card. Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

UPDATE:
Output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`  is

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:
  Installed: 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1
  Candidate: 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20.0.4-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386:
  Installed: 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1
  Candidate: 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20.0.4-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Output of `dpkg -S iris_dri.so` is

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/iris_dri.so
```

and output of `dpkg -S swrast_dri.so` is

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
```

Comment: You need to install the packages listed by `dpkg -S /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so;dpkg -S usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so`. Read `man dpkg`.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` and also `dpkg -S iris_dri.so` with `dpkg -S swrast_dri.so` to the question by editing it.

Comment: Exactly the same problem with Lattice Radiant. Did you solve it?
Partial solution is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841785/libgl-error-for-matlab?rq=1)